# Hardfault when attempting to read unaligned DMA register address on STM32F4

Tags: c, arm, stm32, dma

I'm implementing peripherals dump on STM32F4. I'm reading most peripherals registers byte-by-byte and flush it over UART interface. It works well for almost every peripheral.

When I'm trying to read the DMA1 (0x40026000...) or DMA2 (0x40026400...) registers **byte-by-byte** it fails with precise bus error at 0x40026401.

When I'm trying to read it aligned to 4-byte words, it works fine.

My question is: why it fails on DMA whilst all the other peripherals like SCB, RCC, SPI, UART, TIM and others allow me to do it? Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: You can place a print (or dump to a local array) inside the hard-fault interrupt. What you need to print (or dump) is the CPU registers, in particularly, those that will give you a better indication of what the problem is. My guess - the bus between the CPU and the DMA controller allows only 32-bit access operations.

Comment: Thanks, for suggestion. I've already checked that - Bus Fault Status Register points to precise bus fault at 0x40026401 which is an unaligned address 1 byte after DMA region begins. It looks like it's impossible to read it in unaligned manner and I'm trying to understand why, since all other peripherals accept this approach.

Comment: OK, I posted that as an answer, and now added some info from the data sheet, specifically on DMA, that might shed some more light on this.

Comment: Because it is not memory. It only is seen be the core as the address. You have to  read or write those registers as words (with some exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the bus between the CPU and the DMA controller allows only 32-bit access operations.

You can print (or dump to memory) from inside the hard-fault interrupt.

What you need to print (or dump) is the CPU registers, in particularly, those that may give you a better indication of what the problem is.

For example:

```
void HardFault_Handler(unsigned int* hardfault_args)
{
    printf("R0    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[0]);         
    printf("R1    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[1]);         
    printf("R2    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[2]);         
    printf("R3    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[3]);         
    printf("R12   = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[4]);         
    printf("LR    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[5]);         
    printf("PC    = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[6]);         
    printf("PSR   = 0x%.8X\r\n",hardfault_args[7]);         
    printf("BFAR  = 0x%.8X\r\n",*(unsigned int*)0xE000ED38);
    printf("CFSR  = 0x%.8X\r\n",*(unsigned int*)0xE000ED28);
    printf("HFSR  = 0x%.8X\r\n",*(unsigned int*)0xE000ED2C);
    printf("DFSR  = 0x%.8X\r\n",*(unsigned int*)0xE000ED30);
    printf("AFSR  = 0x%.8X\r\n",*(unsigned int*)0xE000ED3C);
    printf("SHCSR = 0x%.8X\r\n",SCB->SHCSR);                
    while (1);
}
```

Or you can simply stop inside the hard-fault interrupt, and view those registers in your IDE...

From the STM32F4 data sheet:

```
The MPU attributes don't affect DMA data accesses to the memory/peripherals address
spaces. therefore, in order to protect the memory areas against inadvertent DMA accesses,
the MPU must control the SW/CPU access to the DMA registers.
```

So it looks like there are some restrictions specifically with regards to accessing DMA registers.

---

**answer extended by OP according to PaulR's comment:**

Documentation digging confirms that reason is a limitation of DMA AHB slave programming interface.

In DM00031020 chapter **10.2 DMA main features** it's clearly written "AHB slave programming interface supporting only 32-bit accesses". As a contrary, e.g. DMA2D supports 8-bit,16-bit and 32-bit access, thus can be accessed byte-by-byte and doesn't cause bus fault.

Comment: The way I read the quote from the manual, the accesses *by the DMA* are not affected by the MPU. I think that paragraph is unrelated to the OPs problem, as he is reading the DMA control registers from the CPU.

Comment: @PaulR: For the first part of the quote - yes. But the second part of the quote specifically refers to `SW access to the DMA registers` (if I may quote the quote).

Comment: The [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) confirms your initial guess: "The AHB slave port is used to program the DMA controller (it supports only 32-bit 
accesses)"

Comment: @PaulR: Nice! I opened two of them and searched for DMA in general, but didn't bump into this one.

Comment: Thank you both, I've extended @goodvibration answer by latest docs findings and marked as resolved.